# Prove that there does not exist integer solutions for the diophantine equation $x^5 - y^2 = 4$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Prove that there does not exist an integer solution for the diophantine equation $x^5 - y^2 = 4$.

It's obvious that $x$ and $y$ are of the same parity. We can also claim that if $x$ is odd, then it is $1 \pmod 4$. Also, if $x$ and $y$ are even, then $y \equiv 2 \pmod 4\text{ since } x^5 \text{ is a multiple of } 32$ and if $y$ were a multiple of $4$ then it would be at a distance of at least $16$ from $x^5$ or be equal to it.
These are my observations.

How should I proceed with the proof? *Please give hints.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint:  Consider working modulo $11$.

Comment: $11$ is the *only* prime modulus less than $10000$ that works! Any explanation?

Comment: There are not many fifth powers modulo $11$, since $5=\frac{11-1}{2}$.

Comment: Great Answer. But I did not realize the logic behind 'There are not many fifth powers modulo $11$, since $5=\frac{11-1}{2}$.' especially after the 'since'.

Comment: @lhf Did you compute it?

Comment: @Dhruv: By Fermat's Theorem, if $a$ is not divisible by $11$, then $(a^5)^2\equiv 1\pmod{11}$, so $a^5\equiv \pm 1\pmod{11}$.  One has the same phenomenon for $a^k$ whenever $2k+1$ is prime.

Comment: @Dhruv, yes I wrote a program to find a suitable modulus but André beat me to it...

Comment: I really don't understand how to find a suitable modulo. Is there any paper on this?

Comment: For this problem, I gave a suitable modulus. Often modulus $2$, $4$, or $8$ is useful. Every so often other small numbers, like $3$, $5$, $7$, $9$ (which can be useful for cubics). But in many Diophantine problems, modular calculations do not settle the matter, or only give partial help. I don't know of any paper on how to find a suitable modulus. One picks up these things by doing problems.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1749467/x5-y2-4-has-no-solution-mod-m.

Comment: Great answer, and to teach the student to find a suitable modulus would make an invaluable chapter in a graduate level number theory text, even if it is just a collection of problems.

Comment: @lhf the program you or Andre wrote, can I please see the algorithm?