# Prove that there are no positive integers $x$ and $y$ such that $x^3 + y^3 = 10^3$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, diophantine-equations

> Prove that there are no positive integers $x$ and $y$ such that $x^3 + y^3 = 10^3$.

This is a homework question, and I understand that its part of Fermat's Last Theorem, but when I looked that up to try to figure out the homework, I realized that it is way further than what we've learned in class so far. We have to prove this, but the only way I can think to do it is by exhaustion, which would be extremely lengthy. Any little shove in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ must be positive integers then the only possible solutions are when $1\leq x,y<10$, so you only need to check a short list of cases.

Comment: Also $x+y \mid x^3+y^3 = 10^3$ so you only have to check the cases $x+y=2,4,5,10$.

Comment: @mathworker21 How would I do that considering there are multiple solutions to cases such as $x+y=10$?

Comment: There are only finitely many, so just check.....

Answer (score 5):

Here’s the stupidest possible way to do it: $10^3$ is only one thousand, and there are only nine cubes less than that. They are $1$, $8$, $27$, $64$, $125$, $216$, $343$, $512$ and $729$. Since all are less than $500$ except $512$ and $729$, you only need to check whether $488$ or $271$ is on the list, and neither is.

Comment: @BarryCipra, whoops! I'll make the necessary correction when I get to my computer. Thanks for cleaning up after me!

Answer (score 3):

Either both $x$ and $y$ are odd, or both are even. I haven't figured out the odd case yet, but here's the even case:

**Even:**

$(2a)^3+(2b)^3 = 10^3 \implies a^3 + b^3 = 125 \implies (a+b)(a^2 + ab + b^2) = 5 \cdot 25$.

Note that since $x$ and $y$ are positive integers, writing the RHS as $1 \cdot 125$ wouldn't work.

Since $a+b$ is smaller than $a^2+ab+b^2$, we have $a+b = 5$. But then

$a^2+ab+b^2 < a^2 + 2ab + b^2 = (a+b)^2 = 25$.

So no even solution.

Comment: This is irrelevant to the correctness of your answer, but $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

A hint of one way to prove this ...

What are the possible remainders when cubes are divided by $7$?  What is the remainder when $10^3$ is divided by $7$ (more formally what is $n$ $(0 \leq n < 7)$ such that $10^3 \equiv n \mod 7 $)? How can two of the possible remainders sum to $n$, and what does this tell us about $x$ and $y$?

Comment: $7$ and $13$ are the only modulus less than $10000$ for which this argument works.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1749467/x5-y2-4-has-no-solution-mod-m.

Comment: $10^3\equiv -1\pmod 7.$ If $x\not \equiv 0 \pmod 7$ then $x^3\equiv \pm 1 \pmod 7.$  So if $x^3+y^3=10^3$ then $7|x$ or $7|y$ (otherwise $x^3+y^3$ is $\equiv  \pm 2$ or $\equiv 0 \pmod 7).$  So $x=7$ or $y=7, $  because $14^3>10^3.$  But $10^3-7^3=3^2(73)$ is not a cube.

Comment: I think that this is the intended solution as OP suggests they are in an elementary number theory course.

Answer (score 1):

Just for kicks, let's show that not only are there no *positive* integer solutions to $x^3+y^3=10^3$, but there are no solutions if negative integers are allowed as well, i.e., no solutions with $xy\not=0$.

Let $s=x+y$ and $p=xy$.  Then

$$10^3=x^3+y^3=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)=(x+y)((x+y)^2-3xy)=s(s^2-3p)$$

so $s\mid10^3$.  Note that we must have $s\gt0$ (because $x$ and $y$ can't both be negative, and $x^2-xy+y^2$ is necessarily positive if $xy\lt0$), so there are just $16$ possibilities:  $s=2^m\cdot5^n$ with $0\le m,n\le3$.  But we have $s^3\equiv1$ mod $3$, so that cuts things in half:  we need $m+n$ to be even.  The possibilities are $s=1,4,10,250,25,100,40$, and $1000$.  But we can cut things further still.  Solving for $p$ gives

$$p={s^3-10^3\over3s}$$

In order to have $x+y=s$ and $xy=p$, we need $x$ to be an integer solution to the quadratic $x^2-sx+p=0$, which requires, at the very least, that

$$s^2-4p={4\cdot10^3-s^3\over3s}\ge0$$

This limits $s$ to be less than $10\sqrt[3]4$, which is clearly less than $25$, so only $s=1,4$, and $10$ remain.  We can rule out $s=10$ right away, since it give $p=0$ which contradicts the assumption $xy\not=0$.  For the other two cases, the discriminant of the quadratic is

$$s^2-4p={4\cdot10^3-s^3\over3s}=
\begin{cases}1333\quad\text{for }s=1\\
328\quad\text{for }s=4
\end{cases}$$

neither of which is a square.  (Note, if we were only interested in ruling out solutions with positive $x$ and $y$, the condition $p=xy\gt0$ and the formula $p={s^3-10^3\over3s}$ would have said $s\gt10$ right away.)

There may well be a quicker way to do all this; if so I'd be interested to see it.