# Interesting equation over the naturals with powers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have an interesting equation over the naturals.

$x^5=y^2+4$

How do I solve it?

Comment: I'd try factoring over $\Bbb Z[i]$. This is a genus $2$ curve and will have only finitely many rational solutions by Faltings' theorem.

Answer (score 3):

The equation has no solution mod $11$.

Comment: $11$ seems to be the only prime that works. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1749467/x5-y2-4-has-no-solution-mod-m.